# Changing Magento Product Review Page Titles

Tags: product, seo, review

I have found a tutorial, which seems to work only on very old version of Magento, i*t changes title from PRODUCT NAME TO*.

***(Product Name) Review - (Review Title)***

It just displays old default url instead .

> ```
> <?php
>
> class Mage_Review_Block_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
> {
>
>
>       public function __construct()
>         {
>             parent::__construct();
>             $this->setTemplate('review/view.phtml');
>         }
>
>         /**
>          * Retrieve current product model from registry
>          *
>          * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
>          */
>         public function getProductData()
>     {
>         return Mage::registry('current_product');
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Retrieve current review model from registry
>      *
>      * @return Mage_Review_Model_Review
>      */
>     public function getReviewData()
>     {
>         return Mage::registry('current_review');
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Prepare link to review list for current product
>      *
>      * @return string
>      */
>     public function getBackUrl()
>     {
>         return Mage::getUrl('*/*/list', array('id' => $this->getProductData()->getId()));
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Retrieve collection of ratings
>      *
>      * @return Mage_Rating_Model_Mysql4_Rating_Option_Vote_Collection
>      */
>     public function getRating()
>     {
>         if( !$this->getRatingCollection() ) {
>             $ratingCollection = Mage::getModel('rating/rating_option_vote')
>                 ->getResourceCollection()
>                 ->setReviewFilter($this->getReviewId())
>                 ->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
>                 ->addRatingInfo(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
>                 ->load();
>             $this->setRatingCollection( ( $ratingCollection->getSize() ) ? $ratingCollection : false );
>         }
>         return $this->getRatingCollection();
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Retrieve rating summary for current product
>      *
>      * @return string
>      */
>     public function getRatingSummary()
>     {
>         if( !$this->getRatingSummaryCache() ) {
>             $this->setRatingSummaryCache(Mage::getModel('rating/rating')->getEntitySummary($this->getProductData()->getId()));
>         }
>         return $this->getRatingSummaryCache();
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Retrieve total review count for current product
>      *
>      * @return string
>      */
>     public function getTotalReviews()
>     {
>         if( !$this->getTotalReviewsCache() ) {
>             $this->setTotalReviewsCache(Mage::getModel('review/review')->getTotalReviews($this->getProductData()->getId(),
> ```
>
> false, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
>               }
>               return $this->getTotalReviewsCache();
>           }
>
> ```
>     /**
>      * Format date in long format
>      *
>      * @param string $date
>      * @return string
>      */
>     public function dateFormat($date)
>     {
>         return $this->formatDate($date, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_LONG);
>     }
> }
>
>     /**
>      * Set Page title
>      */
>     protected function _prepareLayout()
>     {
>         $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
>         if ($headBlock) 
>         {
>           $title = array();
>           if ($product = $this->getProductData()) 
>           {
>               $title[] = $product->getName() . ' Review';
>           }
>
>           if ($review = $this->getReviewData()) 
>           {
>               $title[] = $review->getTitle();
>           }
>
>           $title = implode(' - ', $title);
>             $headBlock->setTitle($title);
>         }
>
>         return parent::_prepareLayout();
>     }
> }
> ```

http://icebergcommerce.com/software/blog/iss/article/seo-tip-changing-magento-product-review-page-titles/#comments

Has anyone ever figured out a way to display "(Product Name) Review - (Review Title)" for each review in meta title on Magento 1.9.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per as,your question. you want to set `review page title` to ***(Product Name) Review - (Review Title)`.***

***First, you have working on wrong class for set title for review page***. It should be `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View`

### This can be easily achieve by two process.

- Using magento event `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`/`review_product_list`
- Using rewrite class `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View`

Then using `Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($title);` You will set the title of  page.

**Issue:**

But you  will get **logic issue whenever a product have more than one review**. That time you `can use  first review title`

***If you  want to achieve using class rewrite class then you can try***

> ```
> <?php
> class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Block_Review_Product_View  extends Mage_Review_Block_Product_View{
>
>    protected function _prepareLayout(){
>
>       // format (Product Name) Review - (Review Title)
>
>       $title=$this->getProduct()->getName(); 
>       $title=$title.' Review ';
>           // get first time of review from collection
>           if($this->getReviewsCollection()->getSize()){
>               $firstReview=$this->getReviewsCollection()->getFirstItem();
>               $title=$title.'- '.$firstReview->getTitle();
>           }
>        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($title);
>
>      return parent::_prepareLayout();
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Hey, wow, thank you! Shall I just add that code to /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php?

As I tried and titles still did not update

Comment: yes it will works  .It is very bad idea to work on core file on file..Use block class rewrite & event

Answer (score 0):

Try add the above code to viewAction() in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
```

Edit : replace this

```
public function viewAction()
    {
        $review = $this->_loadReview((int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        if (!$review) {
            $this->_forward('noroute');
            return;
        }

        $product = $this->_loadProduct($review->getEntityPkValue());
        if (!$product) {
            $this->_forward('noroute');
            return;
        }

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('review/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

With

```
public function viewAction()
    {
        $review = $this->_loadReview((int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        if (!$review) {
            $this->_forward('noroute');
            return;
        }

        $product = $this->_loadProduct($review->getEntityPkValue());
        if (!$product) {
            $this->_forward('noroute');
            return;
        }
        $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        if ($headBlock)
        {
            $title = array();
            if ($product = $this->getProductData())
            {
                $title[] = $product->getName() . ' Review';
            }

            if ($review = $this->getReviewData())
            {
                $title[] = $review->getTitle();
            }

            $title = implode(' - ', $title);
            $headBlock->setTitle($title);
        }
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('review/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

Do not edit the Core file( you should never do it) , override it then make the changes
 I have not tried it , this i the place it should be you might have to tweak a code a little

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED) in /home/x/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php on line 315`

That line:     protected function _initProductLayout($product)

Comment: Just add  $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
    if ($headBlock) 
    {
     $title = array();
     if ($product = $this->getProductData()) 
     {
      $title[] = $product->getName() . ' Review';
     }
 
     if ($review = $this->getReviewData()) 
     {
      $title[] = $review->getTitle();
     }
 
     $title = implode(' - ', $title);
        $headBlock->setTitle($title);
    } not the whole function     before     $this->loadLayout();  See my edit in answer

Comment: Thanks! While I no longer get any errors, title still goes to magento default

Comment: @try debugging the code is flow is going in if block or is product object is loaded , it will show the the default page only title will be changed